# Why Twig cannot use variable as index for array when I use set as capture?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, set, twig

In Twig, I can do a set in 2 ways

```
{% set car = 'Honda' %}
```

or

```
{% set car %}Honda{%endset%}
```

where the 2nd way is a 'capture'

When I try to use the variable as an index in an array
for e.g.,

```
{{ cars[car].wheels | length }}
```

The 2nd way of setting a variable will not work. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn on debug mode in Twig.
Use the debug extension to view the variable in the 2 scenarios.

The first way

```
{% set car = 'Honda' %}
{% debug car %}
```

will show you that car is still a string Honda

however, the 2nd way

```
{% set car %}Honda{%endset%}
{% debug car %}
```

will show you that car is now a

Twig_Markup Object ( [content:protected] => car )

So do not use capture as a way to set the variable if you want to use it as a key or index in an array.

Update: for Twig version greater than 1.5 use dump to replace debug

eg:

```
{% set car = 'Honda' %}
{% debug car %}
```

eg:

```
{% set car %}Honda{%endset%}
{% debug car %}
```

Comment: @kissmyface http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to/17467#17467

Comment: Looks like debug is deprecated in Twig 1.5. The documentation recommends using dump instead http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/dump.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 2nd way like this (you should trim car variable):

```
{% set car %}Honda{%endset%}

{{ cars[car|trim].wheels | length }}
```